# How to test many cookies in .htaccess with mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make an internal redirection based on the value of two cookies with use of htaccess/mod_rewrite. I don't know how to refer to both values of tested cookies with backreferences. Here is what I want to do:

```
foo = value_of_cookie_foo
bar = value_of_cookie_bar
if (foo AND bar) {
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite/foo/bar [R,L]
}
```

Sadly, the following code does not work. This is because (according to Apache documentation) backreferences apply only for the last `RewriteCond`. The first one is not taken into account.

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/whatever$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} cookie_foo=([^;]+) [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} cookie_bar=([^;]+) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite/%1/%2 [R,L]
```

For cookie `cookie_foo=foo; cookie_bar=bar;` the above code redirects to http://mydomain.com/mysite/bar instead of http://mydomain.com/mysite/foo/bar.

Should I enclose testing of both cookies in one `RewriteCond`? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reorder the cookie values to get them both at once:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/whatever$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (^|;\s*)cookie_foo=([^;]+)
RewriteCond %2;%{HTTP_COOKIE} ^([^;]+)(;\s*|[^;])+cookie_bar=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite/%1/%3 [R,L]
```

This will put the *cookie_foo* value at the beginning to then get the *cookie_bar* value too.

Comment: this one does the trick! Moreover, the cookies' order is not important. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you yry something like this for cookie check:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} cookie_foo=([^;]+);\scookie_bar=([^;]+);? [NC]
```

Comment: thanks! Looks like it should work. However I prefer the solution below, see my comment. Cheers!

Comment: @pete: Agreed that Gumbo's solution is better than this one since it is cookie order agnostic.